# How to set python source code encoding with swig

Tags: python, swig, python-2.x

When I wraps a library with swig

```sh
swig -python my_ext.i
```

This generate a `my_ext.py` file.

How to add file encoding in the first line, when creating my extension with `distutils.extension.Extension` ?

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8
```

I have tried:

```
%pythonbegin %{
# -*- coding: utf-8
%}
```

But my comment is append after swig banner.

Comment: Why? This seems pointless.

Comment: Does your SWIG output include non-ASCII characters without an encoding declaration? If so, that's a SWIG bug. (Wait, no, they changed the default in 3.0 - no encoding declaration is necessary for UTF-8.)

Comment: I use docstrings to generate the documentation. So my `.i` file is utf-8 and contains lots of é, è, à, ... And I also need to maintain py2 code.

Comment: Oh, you're still on Python 2? That'd explain some things.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have found is to override the `build_ext` command:

```py
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:

    class build_ext(_build_ext):

        def swig_sources(self, sources, extension):
            new_sources = _build_ext.swig_sources(self, sources, extension)
            for src in sources:
                py_src = os.path.splitext(src)[0].replace("-", "_") + ".py"
                if os.path.exists(py_src):
                    with open(py_src) as infile:
                        content = infile.read()
                    with open(py_src, "w") as outfile:
                        outfile.write("# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-\n")
                        outfile.write(content)
            return new_sources

else:

    build_ext = _build_ext

...

setup(
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
    ...
)
```